# Kernel and platform files while compiling Android

Tags: android, kernel, platform, android-source

I compiled the kernel files for my device however, I don't know what platform files are for. Could you please tell me what are the functions of "kernel" and "platform" files? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Lucifer: I'm using Samsung S-5360.

Comment: what you want to do by compiling the files ? I am not getting your question.

Comment: @Lucifer: Sorry. I'm trying to build my Android OS after modifying a few files (such as cipher.c and random.c) in the kernel and then I'll install the modified OS onto my device. I built the kernel according to the instructions but I don't know what to do with "platform" files.

Comment: ok, I guess this might be wrong place for such question. try on [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Operating System can be roughly split into 2 parts-

- The Linux Kernel
- The Android Framework.

The Android Framework is on top of the linux kernel and it is that which is referred as **platform**. Platform code consists of the Window manager, Event manager etc. It handles things like what should happen when the screen is touched, how windows are drawn and a host of other things. The linux kernel provides the scheduler ( heart of the OS ), drivers which interact with the H/W and a lot of other stuffs.

In short, the platform talks to the user with the aid of the underlying kernel. *Generally*, in android, most of the platform code is in java and kernel code is predominantly in C.

So until you have modified some platform java files you don't need to compile it. Your `random.c` and `cipher.c` should be part of the kernel and not the platform

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, are kernel and platform installed into the device seperately? I mean after compiling the kernel with modifications, will I also need to install the original platform again onto the device?

Comment: @RubiSharmax Yes, both can be installed separately. You can leave the platform alone. Just install the kernel if you've changed only the kernel binary. Thats what I used to do with samsung phones!

Comment: @Paven Manjunath: Thanks again, your comments are really useful.

Comment: @Paven Manjunath: So can we say: ROM=Kernel+platform?

Comment: ROM is not the right term to be used here. You can call it the Andoird binary. Also, the complete android binary consists of the kernel, the platform bin and much more too ( your resources/default files, system.img etc ).

Comment: @Paven Manjunath: Thanks again Paven.

Answer (score 1):

Android OS consists of 4 main parts: Linux Kernel, Core Libraries, Application Framework and Applications. So everything that is connected with Linux Kernel in Android is usually called kernel and all other layers (except maybe Applications) are platform. When you're downloading AOSP (see instructions on [source.android.com](http://source.android.com/source/index.html)) you download platform where the kernel is usually comes prebuilt. But you can separately download kernel and modify it (what you've done).